# GCloud Load Balancer session affinity cookie `Set-Cookie` header - becomes an error in Firefox due to the misuse of `sameSite` attribute

Tags: firefox, cookies, google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud

According to the manual page: https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/backend-service#http_cookie_affinity

> HTTP cookie affinity routes requests to backend VMs or endpoints in a
>   NEG based on the HTTP cookie named in the HTTP_COOKIE flag. If the
>   client does not provide the cookie, the proxy generates the cookie and
>   returns it to the client in a `Set-Cookie` header.

However due to the new security changes in firefox, the following warning appears:

`Cookie “GCLB” will be soon rejected because it has the “sameSite” attribute set to “none” or an invalid value, without the “secure” attribute. To know more about the “sameSite“ attribute, read https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies`

I could not find a way to configure my load balancer in order to modify the sameSite attribute.

For example opening in mozilla firefox (76.0.1 (64-bit)) the website: https://staging.krizo.dk/ yelds in the console the above warning message. (https://paste.pics/979RL) (image of cookie: https://paste.pics/979TR)

The example backendconfiguration to reproduce:

```
apiVersion: cloud.google.com/v1beta1
kind: BackendConfig
metadata:
  name: example-name-config
spec:
  timeoutSec: 7200
  connectionDraining:
    drainingTimeoutSec: 30
  sessionAffinity:
    affinityType: "GENERATED_COOKIE" #"Client_IP" #ClientIP or NONE
    affinityCookieTtlSec: 86400
```

and the ingress resource:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: gce
    cloud.google.com/neg: '{"ingress": true}'
    beta.cloud.google.com/backend-config: '{"ports": {"80":"example-name-config"}}'
    ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "true"
  labels:
    purpose: example-name-config
  <...>
```

Comment: Do you know any site with this behavior, or how to reproduce in GKE? Also, if you try the same site in Chrome, what happens?

Comment: @KoopaKiller Chrome does not complain; I have edited the post with an example

Comment: I've tested in my firefox browser and didn't get any different results from chrome, DId you fix that?

Comment: Hi, I did not fix it. As I have 0 control on how the GCLB cookie is set. Here is a screenshot of me still getting the warning:

https://paste.pics/979RL

Comment: Its Dec 2020 and this is now an issue.  The cookie is now being blocked due to the inability to set this attribute.  I'm not aware of a fix.