# GKE ingress controller annotations for proxy body size, buffer size and sever snippets

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

I am using `nginx` ingress class presently. I want to change this to `gce` type ingress class. I have used many annotations in ingress with `nginx` type, but I couldn't find the matching annotations for `gce` type. I have listed the annotations below which I have used with `nginx` type ingress:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: cookie
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/large-client-header-buffers: "4 16k"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-buffer-size: "128k"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: "25m"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
    more_clear_headers "Server"
    more_clear_headers "X-Powered-By";
    more_set_headers "Feature-Policy: accelerometer 'none'; camera 'none'; geolocation 'none'; gyroscope 'none'; magnetometer 'none'; microphone 'none'; payment 'none'; usb 'none'"
    more_set_headers "Referrer-Policy: no-referrer"
    more_set_headers "X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff"
    more_set_headers "X-Frame-Options: DENY"
    more_set_headers "X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies: none"
    more_set_headers "X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block";
nginx.org/server-snippets: gzip on;
```

I couldn't find an exact replacement for these annotations in `gce`. Also `gce` type ingress class has limited annotations only as per the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/load-balance-ingress#ingress_annotations). But somehow I have managed to use some annotations in a different way:

1. `affinity` - using [ingress 'session_affinity' backend configuration](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ingress-features#session_affinity), I have achieved this. But still some properties are not applied when using this way. Refer [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62043209/gcloud-load-balancer-session-affinity-cookie-set-cookie-header-becomes-an-er) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49581205/gke-load-balancer-ingress-service-session-affinity-sticky-session).
2. `force-ssl-redirect` - using [ingress 'https_redirect' frontend configuration](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ingress-features#https_redirect), I have achieved this.
3. `configuration-snippet` - using [ingress 'custom_request_headers' backend configuration](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ingress-features#request_headers), I have achieved this. But clearing the response header is not possible here, only we can set some headers.

I can't find a replacement for other annotations such as large-`client-header-buffers`, `proxy-buffer-size`, `proxy-body-size`, `server-snippets` in `gce` type ingress. Anyone faced or know about this case? Could you help me to come out of this?

**Note:** As we are planning to configure cloud armor, we are doing this change. Because, for HTTP(S) type load balancers only we can enable cloud armor, if we create load balancer using `nginx` type ingress class it will create TCP type load balancer by default.

Can anyone suggest us how to use these annotations with `gce` type ingress? Or is there any way to configure cloud armor with `nginx` type ingress?

Comment: Looks like you've found the annotations for the GCE ingress.  Most settings are configured via FrontendConfig (attached to the Ingress resource) and BackendConfig (attached to Service resources) as you've discovered.  K8S Ingress controllers are free to implement any annotations they see fit, so there will not be analogs for every setting across all Ingress controllers.

Comment: Hi @Gari Singh, Thank you for your response. Actually, we have planned to configure Cloud Armor, but using HTTP(S) type load balancers only we can configure that. If we create a load balancer using 'nginx' type ingress class, it will create TCP type load balancer. So, we have to change the ingress class from ‘nginx’ to ‘gce’.

Can you suggest us how to use these annotations with ‘gce’ type ingress? Or is there any other possible way to configure cloud armor with ‘nginx’ type ingress?

Comment: So is the real goal here to use Cloud Armor with nginx ingress or are you ok now using GCE ingress even though it does not support every nginx annotation?

Comment: Hi @Gari Singh, We are not okay with 'gce' ingress unless it supports all our existing annotations. Here, our goal is to enable cloud armor with our current cluster setup which has 'nginx' type ingress. As it's not possible(as per our analysis), we thought to move 'gce' ingress, but some existing annotations are not supported in that case. So we are either okay with 'nginx' ingress if we can configure cloud armor with that or 'gce' ingress with all our existing annotation support.

Comment: Hi @GariSingh, Do you have any updates on this?

Answer (score 0):

As per Gari suggested: if there are no supported annotations in GCE to use it instead of Nginx, then there is no other possible solution, except waiting for the feature implementation that is submitted in [Buganizer](https://issuetracker.google.com/143528734). However, it was submitted 2 years ago and there are ping messages from last month. Let's wait for any update in this thread.

> Note that Cloud Armor is a feature for GKE that only the GCE ingress controller supports. We try to only support features that are portable between cloud providers and baremetal

Please also note that:

> Currently, GCP does not support 3rd party ingresses like Nginx for Cloud Armor and won't be filtered for DDoS attacks.

Comment: Hi @Bazhikov & Wytrzymały Wiktor, Thank you for your responses. Okay, we will wait for some time.